# Calculate a function with smallest relative error

Tags: java, calculus

I need to create a program in Java to calculate the function: **cbrt(1+x²)-x**

With the smallest relative error. But I have no idea the logic for this, can anyone help me?

(Sorry for my poor English)

Comment: If you are asking for code help please post what you have already developed.

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: Actually I was left with doubts on minimizing the error. Maybe it's more of a numerical calculation problem than programming.
I do not know if my code needs to treat each piece of the function individually (first x², then (1 + x²), then cbrt (1 + x²), ...) because I have formulas for relative error only for simple operations like sum And multiplication.

Comment: a) Can you do the computation "by hand"? b) What have you tried so far? c) Did you read the article I linked to?

Answer (score 0):

Use Java's built-in math libraries.

```
double myCalculation(double x) {
    return Math.pow(1.0 + Math.pow(x, 2.0), (1.0/3.0)) - x;
}
```

[Math](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html) is in the `java.lang` package, so it's part of Java's native language; there is no 3rd-party library involved. [Math.pow(double x, double y)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow(double,%20double)) takes two doubles--x and y--and returns the double representation of x^y.

Do note that, using this method, you still need to worry about floating-point rounding error. Whether or not that is important for the types of calculations you're doing is up to you to determine.

Comment: You also need to take the cube root. Either way, you really shouldn't answer "gimme teh codez" questions like this.

Comment: @EJoshuaS Cubic root of x is x ^ (1/3)

Comment: True... slightly embarrassing that I missed that :)

Comment: I had already made a code using the functions, like this:
`y=Math.cbrt(1+Math.pow(x,2))-x;`
But how do I know if this gives me the result with the least relative error? I do not know what to compare the result with since I can put whatever value I want, like x = 2.

Answer (score 0):

If `Math.pow` isn't good enough for calculating the cube root and you want more precision, you can use `BigDecimal` to get as close to correct as you like.  You can use Newton's method or Halley's method until you're close enough.